# Rails testing for params key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I'm trying to sort out a problem where I need to write the following and test to see if a params key is being passed:

```
if params.has_key? :transfer_date(1i)
    params[:call].parse_time_select! :transfer_date
  end
```

I can test against a params key like :transfer but the params being passed by my time parsing gem passes transfer_date(1i), transfer_date(2i), etc.

How do I write the above statement with the right syntax so I can test for the transfer_date(1i) params key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quote the symbol's content:

```
if params.has_key? :'transfer_date(1i)'
```

or, if `params` is guaranteed to be the usual `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`, you could just check for a string key:

```
if params.has_key? 'transfer_date(1i)'
```